# How much damage does a conjured weapon do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As the title, how can you determine how much damage a conjured weapon is doing? Is there anyway to view this stat?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the conjured weapon equipped, go into the item menu and select the weapons tab. (Note: you can only see this tab if you actually have some real weapon in your inventory.)

On the bottom of the screen it will show you the damage of your conjured weapon.

It's kind of a roundabout way, but I haven't found another method of seeing the damage of a conjured weapon.

Answer (score 0):

Uh on my character, with 100 conjuring, and 100 archery, and with all the damage boosting perks for bound wepons, my bound bow only does *slightly* better than an un-upgraded daedric bow. Bound weapons do the same damage as their daedric counterparts (with the necessary perks) except for the war axe (for whatever reason, its equivilant is ebony)