# How strong are the conjured "Bound" weapons compared to their physical counterparts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much damage does a conjured weapon do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35453/how-much-damage-does-a-conjured-weapon-do)

I've really come to enjoy conjuring, especially dual-wielding bound swords.  They weigh nothing, and I get skill just for bringing them out, and the coup-de-grace is that they automatically soul trap (hooray enchanting!).

The issue is though, how much damage am I losing by using conjured weapons over carrying the average/best weapons available to my level?

I have the perk that increases bound weapon damage, and I know it's augmented by my one handed skill, but does my conjuration skill also augment the damage? or just the cost/duration?

Answer (score 3):

They count as Daedric weapons.

Comment: So... pretty strong?

Comment: @Konerak IIRC, Daedric is the highest tier of weapons.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but their base power is close to that of daedric weapons, but untempered. So a freshly created daedic bow will be close to a bound bow, but you can make the real thing WAY stronger through tempering.